# Basic Playwright setup not working in Sveltkit

Tags: svelte, playwright, sveltekit

When i run **npm test** after timeout i get these results:

```
Running 0 tests using 0 workers
[Webserver]
... some unused css selectors messages
[WebServer]
Error: Timed out waiting 60000ms from config.webServer.
```

I did research on google. But materials are very limited and could not resolve my problem.
**npm test:unit** works.

I am out of ideas what can i do. Below is information about the files.

**playwright.config.js**

```
/ @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */
const config = {
    webServer: {
        command: 'npm run build && npm run preview',
        port: 4173
    },
    testDir: 'uat',
    timeout: 6000
};
export default config;
```

**svelte.config.js**

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/ @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} /
const config = {
    onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
    if (warning.code.startsWith('a11y-')) {
      return;
    }
    handler(warning);
  },
    preprocess: [vitePreprocess()],
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};
export default config;
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite'
import { socketPlugin } from './server/socket_plugin.js'

const config = {
    server: {
        port: 3000
    },
    preview: {
        port: 3000
    },
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        socketPlugin
    ],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
}
export default config;
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "playwright test",
    "test:unit": "vitest"
}
```

**directory**

```
...
uat
   test.js
```

**test.js**

```
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';

test('index page has expected h1', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('/');
    expect(await page.textContent('h1')).toBe('Welcome to SvelteKit');
});
```

Comment: Playwright is not finding your test because it should have have a .spec.js or .test.js extension.

Comment: renamed to demo.spec.js. but still get same console output. btw i dont know why does Playwright ignores timeout 6000.

Comment: 6_000 is test timeout, 60_000 that thrown is webserver timeout

Answer (score 2):

Since your app uses 3000 port

```js
/ @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */
const config = {
    webServer: {
        command: 'npm run build && npm run preview',
        timeout: 120 * 1000, // time to launch server, 6o by default
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/', // app url
    },
    testDir: 'uat',
    timeout: 60 * 1000, // test timeout is shared between all tests.
    use: {
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    },
};
export default config;
```

Also, I see you are waiting for 4173 for some reason.
Try to debug - to see the stdout, you can set the `DEBUG=pw:webserver` environment variable.

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#launching-a-development-web-server-during-the-tests

Btw, use latest 1.31.2 ver, some Vite fixes were released https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/21227

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem using sveltekit. Switching out `url` with `port` seemed to fix it for me.

```js
  const port = process.env.CI ? 4173 : 3000;
  //....

  webServer: {
    command: process.env.CI ? 'npm run preview' : 'npm run dev',
    port: port,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
```

Also, `stdout:'pipe'` option may give some usefull hints if you're still stuck.